# How to import old libgdx eclipse project into android studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I'm trying to import old LibGDX eclipse Android games to Android Studio. Some games are easily able to import all module (android , core) and run but some are not able to import, only one android module is being imported . I'm trying to import as a eclipse project.